# Segues among multiple view controllers

Tags: ios

I'm new to programming and I really appreciate all the help so far.

I have a simple app that has 4 view controllers. One view controller is a timer and let's call the others o-stats, d-stats, and st-stats.

At the bottom of each screen I have a button that will send the user to whichever of the other screens they select. I can do segues by ctrl-dragging to the destination screen.

However, that gets messy at run time with all the views that get loaded and not dismissed. I'm new to segues- this is my first time with multiple screens. I'm looking for a way to handle the segues from the button pushes and allow the dismissal of the previous screen to keep the app from running any slower.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: for the easy way, you can use tabbarviewcontroller instead.

Comment: One more thing is using unwind segue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them